# Сделать неактивной кнопку "следующий шаг" пока не заполнены все поля

Tags: javascript, html

Вот такая форма (возможно будут дополнения в виде строк):

```
<input type="text" class="putName" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" required>
<input name="phone" type="tel" class="putPhone" placeholder="Телефон" required>
<input type="text" class="putemail" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email" required>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn" value="Следующий шаг" onClick="window.open('https://ru.stackoverflow.com')">
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что прописать, чтобы кнопка "следующий шаг" была не активна, пока не заполнены все поля формы?
Вот по этому примеру не могу разобраться, к сожалению:
    http://jsfiddle.net/t52ka/2/

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Сначало необходимо обернуть ваш html код в тег form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прежде всего Вам нужно обернуть все ваши инпуты в тег `<form>`. 
С тегом form для простой и нативной валидации достаточно будет задать атрибут required Вашему инпуту, чтобы сделать его обязательным. 
Добавление `onkeyup='checkParams()'` к каждому инпуту позволяет проверять валидность вашей формы по каждому следующему нажатию клавиши в пределах конкретного инпута.
Подробнее тут: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onkeyup.asp.
`onClick` в инпуте заменяется на `onSubmit` в форме.
Решение вашей проблемы можете найти здесь:
http://jsfiddle.net/5fpzbwuq/