# Как сделать кнопку неактивной, если есть пустые поля

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Я не очень хорош в программирование, но столкнулся с такой проблемой:

У меня есть html страница входа , login i password - поля для ввода, и есть кнопка "войти", как мне сделать, чтобы если поле login или password пустое , кнопка была неактивной.

p.s если можно то детальнее как сделать, перепробовал много вариантов, но увы не получилось, надеюсь на помощь

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сделать неактивной кнопку "следующий шаг" пока не заполнены все поля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033230/%d0%a1%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b3-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8f)

Answer (score 0):

[Сделать неактивной кнопку "следующий шаг" пока не заполнены все поля](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1033230/%D0%A1%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B3-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F)

Возможно, это вам поможет. Еще советую погуглить информацию по теме "валидация форм на веб-страницах"

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).